# How would I modify an inline function parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameters

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="CheckBoxSelect('/prosearch.aspx?rid=123452+45673+0.03');">
```

Hi all, 
I'm trying to access this particular inline click event's parameter for CheckBoxSelect. Assuming I cannot directly edit the CheckBoxSelect function; What steps would it take for me to be able to edit the CheckBoxSelect's parameters?

Ultimately Im trying to add an extra line of text to each checkbox's click event parameters.

Not 100% sure where to start but I figured this would be a good place to brainstorm. Jquery is on the table as well

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: By definition of an inline binding, the method used by it has to be global.  So there's nothing stopping you from replacing that attribute with a new version giving a different argument to the function.

Answer (score 1):

What about changing the function that you're calling on click and wrapping the `CheckBoxSelect()` call with additional code? It's unclear what you mean by "trying to add an extra line of text to each checkbox's click event parameters", but perhaps you could perform whatever you need to do in the wrapping function, e.g. `MySelect()` below.

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="MySelect('/prosearch.aspx?rid=123452+45673+0.03');"> 

<script>
function MySelect(url) {
    // Let's modify the url as an example
    let newUrl = url + "&myparam=2112";
    CheckBoxSelect(newUrl);
}
</script>
```

If you need to replace the checkbox onclick altogether you could select all checkboxes and swap in the new function.

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var newUrl = 'http://asdf.com';

for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].type.toLowerCase() == 'checkbox') {
        inputs[i].onclick = () => MySelect(newUrl);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did this help solve your problem? If not, could you give some more insight into the `CheckBoxSelect()` function?

Comment: Thanks for the response, Ed!

Ive been trying to use your solution as a spring board. One issue im having is that I do not have direct access to the list of checkboxs so I am not able to directly change the click event. Hopefully I have explained this right.

All checkBoxSelect() does is take the argument entered and use window.location to redirect to that url/argument.

Comment: I added some code above to replace the checkbox onclick attributes. You could potentially run this code after the checkboxes have been added to the page.